# How to get Class<java.lang.Long> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, querydsl

Writing some querydsl code. In Java I would do like this:

```
@Test
void countTest() {
    NumberPath<Long> cnt = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "count");
    NumberPath<Long> typeId = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "type_id");

    List<Long> fetched = sql.select(typeId)
            .from(SQLExpressions.select(tGroup.typeId.as(typeId), tGroup.count().as(cnt))
                    .from(tGroup)
                    .groupBy(tGroup.typeId))
            .where(cnt.gt(100L)).fetch();
    System.out.println(fetched);
}
```

Notice this `Long.class` in `Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, ...)`

If I create a `.kt` file and copy-paste the above Java code, it will be converted by Intellij to:

`Expressions.numberPath(Long::class.java, ...)`.

So the resulting Kotlin code I have is:

```
val cnt = Expressions.numberPath(Long::class.java, "count")
val typeId = Expressions.numberPath(Long::class.java, "type_id")

val fetched = sql.select(typeId)
        .from(SQLExpressions.select(QTGroup.tGroup.typeId.`as`(typeId), QTGroup.tGroup.count().`as`(cnt))
                .from(QTGroup.tGroup)
                .groupBy(QTGroup.tGroup.typeId))
        .where(cnt.gt(100L)).fetch()
println(fetched)
```

Now when I run the code, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported target type : long

    at com.querydsl.core.util.MathUtils.cast(MathUtils.java:86)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberExpression.cast(NumberExpression.java:178)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberExpression.gt(NumberExpression.java:337)
    at project.dao.QuerydslKotlinCountTest.countTest(QuerydslKotlinCountTest.kt:30)
```

So it's not a `Class<java.lang.Long>` which I would expect, but some class `Class<long>` (never seen this before and can not get it programmatically with `Class.forName("long")`).

So, how do I make this simple piece of code work in Kotlin?
If I replace `Long::class.java` with `java.lang.Long::class.java`, the code does not compile:

```
Error:(27, 104) Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun `as`(p0: Path<Long!>!): NumberExpression<Long!>! defined in com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberExpression
public open fun `as`(p0: String!): NumberExpression<Long!>! defined in com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberExpression
```

The only way I made it work is using a boxed java primitive: `java.lang.Long.valueOf(1).javaClass`, but it looks ugly.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `KClass`'s [`javaObjectType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) property instead of `java`, e.g.:

```
1L::class.java // returns long
1L::class.javaObjectType // returns java.lang.Long
```

From its documentation:

> [...] In case of primitive types it returns corresponding wrapper classes.